Object present on multiple pages in Inkscape
Inkscape 1.2 has introduced multiple-page documents..
It would be convenient if one could replicate an object (or rather a group or layer) created on one page onto a selection of other pages. E.g., you create a title-box on the top of page 1, and want to duplicate it to all pages. Ideally there could be some original-clone relation, where editing the original/master would repeat the edit to all clones/slaves, but editing the clones/slaves would edit only itself. For multipage document, positioning should ideally be also affected.
I've tried to find a way to do this with the existing tools (context menu, layers, clones) but I haven't found a way to do this.
Is there a trick/an extension to do this already? Does it correspond to current work-in-progress or an existing feature request?

There's no built in master page functionality in Inkscape, not even in Adobe Illustrator. It's not something commonly found in vector image editors. This is something you can find in dedicated page layout software such as Scribus or Adobe InDesign.
Anyway it is possible to do it manually in Inkscape

Create your first page with all the common elements, and draw a rectangle with no fill or stroke, making sure it is snapped to the page boundary. Select all and group.

Add as many new pages as you want

Select the group on the first page, and create a clone.

Click and drag the clone until it snaps to the next page

Press Ctrl + Alt + D repeatedly, to repeat the duplicate clone on every page


Now you will have clones on the other pages, with the clone source on the original page.
You can edit the clone source by double clicking on it to enter the group, and then adjust anything. The clones will update on all the other pages.

Edit: at the suggestion of @joojaa
It's also possible to use Paste on Page, for pasting the clone to individual pages in position on the page. However, you need to switch pages using the page selector at the bottom of the application before pasting.

Yeah but illustrator has the feature op is asking for. If you ise the paste in front/back it pastes it in the same location on the newly selected page without needing to aim it in place

There's no need to aim it in place in Inkscape. It will snap to the page bounds, and you only need to do it once, then repeat the duplicates.

Also Inkscape has it a similar feature: paste on page. But it's a pain to use for this. The method in my answer is easier and quicker to set up.

Maybe its easier if all your pages are side by side but the paste on page is better if you want to have something on the first and last page for example, or your pages arent leatly arranged in rows for some reason or another. But for completeness it would have been better if you said so

@joojaa Yeah sure. But at least option is there. So, you can use whichever floats your boat really. I will add it to the answer though.
